# PHP not compiling to IIS 7

Tags: php, iis-7, fastcgi

I have set up an IIS 7 to a Windows Server machine. The idea is to access a working php site through a network computer and for the php to be able to be compiled.

Steps i did:

1. Downloaded PHP 5.6.31 (i have to use the specific version)
2. Unzip php files in c:\php directory.
3. Rename php-ini-production to php.ini
4. Copy the same file to c:\Windows
5. Create a website in IIS.
6. Added 2 bindings to website with following data:
   -Type: http, host name: test.local, port: 81, ip address: *
   -Type; http, host name: blank, port: 81, ip address: the ip address of the 
     Workstation hosting the IIS
7. Added at IIS site and new website at Handler mappings the following:
   request path: *.php, Module: FastCgiModule, Executable: C:\php\php-cgi.exe
   and clicked request permissions and on Mapping tab i checked Invoke handler only if request is mapped to  and i selected File or folder
8. Added at IIS  and new website at MIME types the following:
    file name extension: .php, MIME type: application/x-httpd-php
9. At IIS at ISAPI and CGI restrictions i added php-cgi.exe path and clicked Allow extension path to execute.
10. I installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4
11. In php.ini file (the one i renamed above), i uncommended and set values for the below:

    -fastcgi.impersonate = 1
    -cgi.fix_pathinfo =
    -cgi.force_redirect = 0 
    -extension_dir = 'ext'
12. From control panel from System->Properties->Advanced system settings->Environmental variables, at the end i added ;c:\php
13. Restarted iis

Now when on server i run server's ip for example: 10.0.0.1:81/index.php (where index.php is a file inside my website) i get a http Error 500, C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly with error code: 0xc0000135

When i run the same from network computer i get just a 500-Internal server error.

When at network computer i try to access the index.php file as a file (network location) i see just the php code and not the compilation.

Any ideas?Thank you in advance

Comment: If you're getting an error 500, it's a code issue that PHP is running into when it tries to process your code. Look for your server error logs to find out the reason.

Comment: take a look about phpmanager and WPI

Comment: You're much more likely to find someone who can answer this question if you move it to serverfault.

Comment: I installed PHP Manager and fixed all the issues. Now when i am trying to access this site i get a message: The webpage cannot be found

Comment: Actually now i get a 500 error with message: File monitoring is enabled for a file which could not be found

Comment: I added Read privileges to c:\PHP folder, restarted IIS and it worked like a charm. Thank you MacBooc!

Comment: If you found the answer(s), post them as an answer and accept it.